# start a new activity button pressing a button

Tags: android

I want a new activity to start when i press the "createAppointment" button but so far when i click the button, the application crashes.

creation for button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/crtApp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Appointment"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

createApp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createAppointment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36sp"
        android:text="Create Appointment"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleOfAppointment"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleappointment"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeappointment"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timeappointment"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsappointment"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detailsappointment"
        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
         />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01" 
        android:text="Save"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

CreateAppointment.java

```
package com.examples;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CreateAppointment extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createapp);
    }

}
```

code for the button to start a new activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_calendar_view);
    Button createAppointment = (Button)findViewById(R.id.crtApp);
    createAppointment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CREATEAPP"));           
        }
    });
}
```

LOG CAT

```
04-25 15:17:13.719: W/dalvikvm(460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CREATEAPP }
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.examples.SimpleCalendarViewActivity$1.onClick(SimpleCalendarViewActivity.java:60)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 15:17:13.779: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the logcat error you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understand well, you want to start an activity on button pressed.Then you should have something like this :

```
createAppointment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(your_context, CreateAppointment.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

hope it helps!
(for better understanding post your error log :) )

Comment: what do you mean by "your_context"

Comment: you should have this in an activity no? then replace your_context with <name_of_activity>.this (i should've said your activity not your context)

Comment: so you mean it will be like (Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateAppointment.class); ?

Comment: whcih activity you talking you please?

Comment: public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
Parameters:
packageContext A Context of the application package implementing this class.
cls The component class that is to be used for the intent.

Comment: the activity in whitch you have declared your button end implemented his on click listener :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the activity is in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: i have added the activity in the androoid manifest.xml and i will edit to post up the logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateAppointment.class));
```

And also like kailoon said, "Check to make sure the activity is in the AndroidManifest.xml file."

Comment: thanks mate!!!!! jumped up!!!!! when it worked!!!!! loooool btw what does getBaseContext() mean?

Comment: getBaseContext() returns the context, you could also use Activity.this. But be careful when using new Intent(this, Lala.class), because in your case "this" will refer to the OnClick and not your Activity

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the activity in the menifest file?

Besides try:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(pkgname, activity name);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Button />` needs to have the `android:onClick="your method name here"`attribute

and Java code should look something like this

```
public void methodName(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassName.class);
  startActivity(intent)
}
```